# Converting Python file to Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I have this Python file:

```
class Get:

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = get_date(i)
        self.df = self.get_file()

    def get_file(self):
        try:
            ...
            return df
        except Exception as e:
            return ...

    def get_date(self,i):
        dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=i)
        return dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    def put(self,df):
        ....


class Fix:
    def __init__(self,df):
        ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(4, 0, -1):
        get = Get(i)
        fix = Fix(get.df)
        get.put(fix.df)
```

Basically this code generates 4 last dates and run the functions over these dates (update statistics etc...)

[At first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784368/convert-python-script-to-airflow-pythonoperators) I wanted to convert each function into a PythonOperator and then schedule it but I don't think this will work. I don't know how to convert the Classes and the parameters that are transferred between them.

This is what the code does if I run it on 2018-Jun-12 and below what it should be with Airflow:
[image]

Is there a template that I can use or any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730297/python-script-scheduling-in-airflow

Comment: @YashKumarAtri This explain how to use the python script and call functions in it. This is not what I want. I want to delete the python script and create it as Airflow DAGs. I don't understand how do I convert it. In the script I have a loop. in the Airflow I shouldn't have loop i should have each run should with different value of i

Comment: I recommend working through the official tutorial https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html since there are many specific several parts here which would have to be explained.

Comment: Aside of that, you are right. Airflow will take over scheduling and you can put the code in the DAG - but you don't need to, you could call the same way as you are calling from main.

Answer (score 5):

you can either execute your script using BashOperator without any changes of your script:

```
dag = DAG('{NAME_OF_THE_DAG}', schedule_interval='daily', 
default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id = '{NAME_OF_TASK}',
    dag = dag,
    bash_command = python {NAME_OF_THE_FILE_TO_EXECUTE}.py')
```

or use PythonOperator:

1. update your code to create *main* function in your script:

   ```
   def main():
       for i in range(4, 0, -1):
       get = Get(i)
       fix = Fix(get.df)
       get.put(fix.df)
   ```
2. define and execute the dag:

   ```
   dag = DAG('{NAME_OF_THE_TASK}', schedule_interval = 'daily', 
   default_args=default_args)

   t1 = PythonOperator(
       task_id = '{NAME_OF_TASK}',
       dag = dag,
       python_callable = main)
   ```